# Simplest way to catch JS errors

Tags: javascript, stack-trace, stacktrace.js

I've been doing some research into how we can catch JavaScript errors, and then send them off to our own system for *internal logging* (so we can try and replicate where possible, and fix any possible bugs). So far I have found quite a few paid services:

- http://newrelic.com/sp/javascript-errors
- https://trackjs.com/
- https://raygun.io

The **TrackJS** one does look interesting, but we really can't afford to be spending out yet more money each month. I then came across this libray:

http://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/stacktrace-js

I can't seem to get it going though. Here is what I'm trying:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, col, error) {
    StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback);
};

var callback = function(stackframes) {
    var stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function(sf) {
        return sf.toString();
    }).join('\n');
    console.log(stringifiedStack);
};

var errback = function(err) {
        console.log(err);
};

StackTrace.get().then(callback).catch(errback);
```

... and all I get back is:

> TypeError: ErrorStackParser is undefined
>
> var stackframes = ErrorStackParser.parse(error);

Can anyone else suggest a solution, or see what I'm doing wrong with the **stacktrace.js** script?

**UPDATE:** With the help below, I was able to at least get it to do something now. Turns out you need multiple js libs:

- https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js
- https://github.com/stacktracejs/error-stack-parser
- https://github.com/stacktracejs/stack-generator

However,  I still can't seem to get it going.

```
var callback = function(stackframes) {
    console.log(stackframes)
    var stringifiedStack = stamap(function(sf) {
        return sf.toString();
    }).join('\n');
    console.log(stringifiedStack);
};

var errback = function(err) { console.log(err.message); };

 try {
    foo;
 } catch(e) {
    StackTrace.get().then(callback).catch(errback);
 }
```

While I now get errors logged in the console, the line numbers and error messages are less than useless :( Example:

```
.get()@https://cdn.steampunkjunkies.net/2014/js/scripts-all11.js:5:19706
{anonymous}()@https://cdn.steampunkjunkies.net/2014/js/scripts-all11.js:84:2
```

Line 84 is the caller function:

`StackTrace.get().then(callback).catch(errback);`

...and line 5, is the minified include of stacktrace.min.js (in my main JS file)

I'm a bit baffled as to how we can even get any useful information out of this :/

**UPDATE 2**: Ok, I'm getting closer!

```
var callback = function(stackframes) {
    var stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function(sf) {
        return sf.toString();
    }).join('\n');
    alert(stringifiedStack);
};

var errback = function(err) { console.log(err.message); };

 try {
    var foo = 0;
    foo / 1;

    aklert;

    test;
 } catch(e) {
    StackTrace.fromError(e).then(callback).catch(errback);
 }
```

This now prints out an **alert()** message:

> {anonymous}()@https://cdn.steampunkjunkies.net/2014/js/scripts-all11.js:73:1

However, thats not all the information I need. Obviously it needs a nice message (i.e `var x cannot be undefined`)

Anyone got any ideas?

I did try storing them in an array (with the line number and col number), but that doesn't work across all browsers (and ironically, the debug code caused a fatal :))

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, well we are getting closer :)

```
var callback = function(stackframes) {
    var stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function(sf) {
        return sf.toString();
    }).join('\n');
    alert(stringifiedStack);
};

var errback = function(err) { console.log(err.message); };

window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, col, error) {
    var callback = reportWithMessage(msg);
    StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback);
};


function reportWithMessage(message) {
    return function report(stack) {
        var yourErrorCollectorUrl = 'https://steampunkjunkiesdev.net/cgi-bin/debug.cgi';
        stack.message = message;
        StackTrace.report(stack, yourErrorCollectorUrl);
    };
}

 try {
    var foo = 0;
    foo / 1;

    aklert;

    test;
 } catch(e) {
    StackTrace.get().then(reportWithMessage()).catch(errback);
 }
```

[image]

Line 92 is this one}:

```
StackTrace.get().then(reportWithMessage()).catch(errback);
```

...so all its doing, is telling me that this function was called, but it no line number for the actual error.

Any ideas? I can't believe how complicated it is to catch JS errors and just report them back to a script. You would have thought with the last 20+ years of the Internet developing, something more compliant would have been developed for us developers :/

Comment: `ErrorStackParser is undefined` makes me feel like it's not installed / imported on your file. Did you follow [the installation guide](http://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/error-stack-parser) ?

Comment: @pistou thanks for the reply. I run `npm install stacktrace-js` to get the JS file - then I include the JS file (prior to my own code), and finally in my own code I have the code in the above. Maybe I'm missing a step?

Comment: I don't know StackTrace.JS but as far as I understand their website, it seems like `stacktrace-js` and `error-stack-parser` are two separated libraries (maybe one depending on the other)

Comment: @pistou - ah, well that would explain part of it! I'm used to all the modules for lib being in one download. I don't get any errors now, but I'm a bit baffled as to the error stack being outputted: `.get()@https://cdn.steampunkjunkies.net/2014/js/scripts-all11.js:8:19706
{anonymous}()@https://cdn.steampunkjunkies.net/2014/js/scripts-all11.js:25:1 `. Line 25 is the place where the debug is called: `StackTrace.get().then(callback).catch(errback); ` ... but it doesn't seem to give any other info (I've intentionally left a syntax error in the file, but nothing comes up)

Comment: @AndrewNewby you should post your solution that resolved this error, and then ask a new question for additional help

Comment: @Adjit - that wasn't the solution to what I was asking (only part of it). I've updated my question above with more sample code. I'm getting there, but there is just the final bit of the error message that I just can't work out :(

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm the creator of stacktrace.js. You're welcome to email me for help at me@eriwen.com anytime, but of course asking on SO is effective (I hope :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry for your troubles getting started. Please use `dist/stacktrace.min.js` which has all dependencies bundled. I filed this issue so we can make this clearer and others avoid the pain you've encountered: https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js/issues/140

Regarding the Error message, it seems like you can do something with the `msg` parameter of `window.onerror` in your error reporting system. I understand that it's not straight-forward given there is no obvious place to store messages.

How about this?

```
window.onerror = function(msg, file, line, col, error) {
    var callback = reportWithMessage(msg);
    StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback);
};


function reportWithMessage(message) {
    return function report(stack) {
        var yourErrorCollectorUrl = 'https://yourdomain.com/ec';
        stack.message = message;
        // HTTP POST with {message: String, stack: JSON}
        StackTrace.report(stack, yourErrorCollectorUrl);
    };
}
```

Outside of `window.onerror` you can maybe do:

```
StackTrace.get().then(reportWithMessage()).catch(errorhandler);
```

**UPDATE**: In the case where you've caught an Error, you want to use

```
StackTrace.fromError(error).then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sample code - that should do just what I need :) No need to apologize about it being confusing - I just appreciate the time you have spent on the project (I know as a coder, how time consuming stuff like this can be!)

Comment: not sure if this is a bug or not, but I can't seem to get the value passed in with `var yourErrorCollectorUrl = 'https://steampunkjunkies.net/cgi-bin/debug.cgi';`. I see the request, but **QUERY_STRING** is empty (for both `post` and `get`). Am I missing something?

Comment: Mmm actually, maybe its not working for me :( I'll update my post above with the code I'm using, and what its outputting

Comment: @AndrewNewby See my updated answer. I'm going to assume that __QUERY_STRING__ is something specific to CGI for getting the query string of a request. If that is the case, note that StackTrace.report() does an HTTP POST so you're looking for the stacktrace in the POST body.

Comment: ah ok, makes sense. `$ENV{QUERY_STRING}` is the POST/GET request passed into a script. Its weird, as it looks like its passing something along - but then Firebug shows nothing up. I think I'm going to take a break from this, and come back to it with a fresh mind. Its doing my head in :)